# Save python log in a file is not real time

Tags: python, bash, buffer, io-redirection

In `bash` I can run something like this ....

```
~> ping google.com >> log.txt
```

In log.txt:

```
PING google.com (216.239.38.120) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from any-in-2678.1e100.net (216.239.38.120): icmp_seq=1 ttl=104 time=64.2 ms
64 bytes from any-in-2678.1e100.net (216.239.38.120): icmp_seq=2 ttl=104 time=61.5 ms
... (real time like a stream)
```

But when I run a`python` file, It doesn't work like `ping` 
Example:

```
#ding.py
from time import sleep
while True :
    print('ding')
    sleep(0.7)
```

Run:

```
~> python ding.py
#ding
#ding 
# ....
```

But run with `>>` :

```
~> python ding.py >> log.txt
```

In `log.txt`

```
<nothing>
```

And after I click on `Ctrl + C` , lots of `ding` appears in `log.txt` 
In `log.txt` after `Ctrl + C`:

```
ding
ding
ding
.....
#log.txt becomes full in a secound
```

Thank's for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `stdout` is not being flushed often enough. Usually it's not a big problem, but if it's important to you, try adding `flush=True` to your `print` calls or running python with `-u` flag to force stdin/stdout to be unbuffered.

Related question: [How can I flush the output of the print function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-the-print-function)